# String will not draw

Tags: java, string, graphics, drawing, slick2d

Almost 2 days and i still haven't figured this out. I'm pretty sure i have insomnia now, and i just want to know how to do this. The string i want to draw is in the startGame() of the Square class. That method is being called in my NormalMode class in startNormalMode(). Went to sleep at 9pm woke up at 11:30pm, now it is 3:05 am and i still cannot sleep because of this problem. As much info as possible is appreciated, i just wan't to become a better programmer. There's nothing better than experience.

My square class:

```
package data.src;

import java.util.Random;




import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class Square {

    private StateBasedGame game;
    boolean correct;
    boolean clickable;
    boolean clicked;
    boolean started;
    int squares;
    public Image squareIncorrect;
    public Image squareCorrect;
    public  Graphics g;



    //For drawing these images from other classes



    {
        try {
            squareIncorrect = new Image("res/squareIncorrect.png");
        } catch (SlickException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            squareCorrect =  new Image("res/squareCorrect.png");
        } catch (SlickException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Square() {



    }

    public boolean checkCorrect(){
        return correct;

    }
    public boolean checkClickable(){
        return clickable;
    }

    public boolean checkClicked(){
        return clicked;

    }

    public int returnNumberOfSquares(){
        return squares;

    }
    //Draw appropriate square on screen depending on the creatRandom. CREATE THE RANDOM FIRST!
        public void squareDraw(int x ,int y, Graphics g)throws SlickException{

            if(correct == true){
                g.drawImage(squareCorrect, x, y);
                started = true;
            }
            else if(correct == false){
                g.drawImage(squareIncorrect, x, y);
            started = true;
            }
    }

    public void createRandom(){

        Random rand = new Random();
        int sRand = rand.nextInt(2);

            if(sRand == 0){
                correct = false;
                clickable = true;
                clicked = false;
                System.out.println("This square is a phony!");

            }
            else if(sRand == 1){
                correct = true;
                clickable = true;
                clicked = false;
                System.out.println("This is a true Square!");
                squares = squares+1;
            }
        }

    public void startGame(Graphics g, GameContainer container)throws SlickException{
        System.out.println("It works.");
        g.drawString("Remember the blue squares! The game will start in 5 seconds!", 200, 300);


    }




    public void youWin(int x, int y, Graphics g){
        if(squares == 0){
            g.drawString("You win!", x, y);
            try {
                wait(4000);
                game.enterState(0);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

My NormalMode class:

```
package data.src;

import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class NormalMode extends BasicGameState {

    private Square[][] square = new Square[4][4];
    private Square squareChecker;
    Graphics g;


    public NormalMode() {


                }

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer arg0, StateBasedGame Game)throws SlickException {
        squareChecker = new Square();
                    for(int i = 0; i < square.length; i++){
                        for(int j = 0; j < square.length; j++){
                            square[i][j] = new Square();
                            square[i][j].createRandom();

                        }
            }
                    startNormalMode(arg0);
    }                



    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, Graphics g)
            throws SlickException{

                square[0][0].squareDraw(100, 300, g);
                square[0][1].squareDraw(150, 300, g);
                square[0][2].squareDraw(200, 300, g);
                square[0][3].squareDraw(250, 300, g);

                square[1][0].squareDraw(100, 400, g);
                square[1][1].squareDraw(150, 400, g);
                square[1][2].squareDraw(200, 400, g);
                square[1][3].squareDraw(250, 400, g);

                square[2][0].squareDraw(100, 500, g);
                square[2][1].squareDraw(150, 500, g);
                square[2][2].squareDraw(200, 500, g);
                square[2][3].squareDraw(250, 500, g);

                square[3][0].squareDraw(100, 600, g);
                square[3][1].squareDraw(150, 600, g);
                square[3][2].squareDraw(200, 600, g);
                square[3][3].squareDraw(250, 600, g);


                    }

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, int delta)
            throws SlickException {

    }

    @Override
    public int getID() {
        return 3;
    }


public void startNormalMode(GameContainer container)throws SlickException{

        Graphics g1 = container.getGraphics();


        squareChecker.startGame(g1, container);

    }
}
```

P.S. :  I am using slick2D library, and there are no errors, the string just doesn't appear on screen.

Comment: You know you're tired when you start pep-talking yourself in the question. I just realized that.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if this would be the solution, since I don't use StateBasedGame (Which I should), but have you checked on the layering of the images / text being drawn? The element being drawn first will be covered up by the last element that is being drawn. Does the console log show up? Why do you have a random `try` `catch` in space?

Comment: @Twister1002 I'm guessing your correct. I have just gathered enough information to conclude that the Graphics references that I made are correct. Since i just tried the g.setBackground() to see if it worked, which it did. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment made in Orginal Post, Just check the elements in which your game is rendering the graphics. The first element will be covered up by the last element that is being drawn.

If more information is needed, please let me know and I will do what I can!